# Is using an EntityDataSource in keeping with the MVC pattern?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, radgrid, entitydatasource

I'm utterly new to APS.NET and in particular the MVC model...!

I have a Telerik RadGrid control that I'm using. Until now (following NerdDinner) I was having the Model passed back to the view and this provided access to the various properties I wanted.

eg: `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MySqlMvc.Helpers.PaginatedList<MySqlMvc.Models.Customer>>`

.. lets me loop around the Model object and extract Customer data. This RadGrid control, however, needs me to use an EntityDataSource (hooked up via the designer).

Does this have implications for maintaing the MVC pattern? I'm a little confused about how the EntityDataSource works in relation to my Model.

EDIT: I do know there is an MVC version of the RadGrid but we also need the RadScheduler and a few others.. besides that, I'd still like to know the impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using a server control doesn't keep with the MVC pattern. Use the EntityDataSource in your ASP.NET web form applications.

Comment: Thank you. I'll research further where to go from here.